# Selinux sshd mismatch boolean settings vs permanent ones

Tags: centos, ssh, selinux

I got my centreon using sshd to connect to my servers with one user which don't have password set.
After one :

```
sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

I apply :

```
ausearch -c "sshd" --raw | audit2allow -M my-sshd
semodule -X 300 -i my-sshd.pp
```

But the problem is persistant and centreon cannot connect.

*Invalid AVC allowed in current policy
type=AVC msg=audit(1684226954.617:1575992): avc:  denied  { read } for pid=16244 comm="sshd" name="authorized_keys" dev="dm-0" ino=1458525 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0*

```
audit2allow -w -a
type=AVC msg=audit(1684224853.222:1574641): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=10255 comm="sshd" name="authorized_keys" dev="dm-0" ino=1458525 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
        Was caused by:
                Unknown - would be allowed by active policy
                Possible mismatch between this policy and the one under which the audit message was generated.

                Possible mismatch between current in-memory boolean settings vs. permanent ones.
```

Any idea about a clue ? Thanks